# WebClient read the file date

Tags: c#, winforms, attributes, webclient, launcher

I'm trying to make a launcher, that download some game files, if their "last modifed date" is different of the files, already on your harddrive.

For downloading the files on the interweb, you'd have to use WebClient.DownloadFile() but I can't seem to find the method to actually check attributes on the file online, like the Creation Date.

Is this actually something that exist, or should I go about it another way?

I should probably mention, that i'm using C# with Windows Application to build the launcher.

**UPDATE**: I've found a solution, the answer is down below.

Comment: In HTTP you normally use the _Last-Modified_ header.

Comment: I would create an extra file containing the creationdate of the files. MyOnlineFile.jpg.info

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen that would mean an extra HTTP request for each file, not much bandwidth efficient. Maybe a unique file with all the modified dates, but the _Last-Modified_ header should do the job.

Comment: My first thought were a manifest file containing all creationdates etc..

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen yes if it has not much access to server-side technologies and must go with static content, I agree with you, IF the _Last-Modified_ header that is made for that does not works.

Comment: Well, with the limitations of `WebClient` I think the @Jeroen van Langen is better for you (I don't find methods in `WebClient` for access of the HTTP headers). So you can go with `WebRequest` and check the headers without needing other files, but it will be harder to implement on client side depending on your skills, or you can chose the suggested idea of a file with the modified dates, that would put more effort to maintain that list.

Comment: He could create a aspx thats gets all file creation dates in the directory and pass it as xml back to the client. (dynamic list of creationdates) **If** the website is his code.

Comment: quote from my recent comment: _yes if it has not much access to server-side technologies and must go with static content_ :)

Comment: The point of going the way of by Creation Date, was to make the job easier for me, whenever an update is out. I just have to replace the game files, with the new ones, and the launcher will automaticlly notice the date is different and download them.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, by doing alot of research and googling!

This is what I came up with, which works. I don't know if its the best option, but it'll do for now I guess.

```
HttpWebRequest gameFile = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ONLINEFILE_URL);
HttpWebResponse gameFileResponse = (HttpWebResponse)gameFile.GetResponse();

DateTime localFileModifiedTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(LOCALFILE_PATH);
DateTime onlineFileModifiedTime = gameFileResponse.LastModified;

if (localFileModifiedTime >= onlineFileModifiedTime) {
    //Play Game
} else {
    //Download new Update
}
```

Comment: I said you exactly that in my comments! Anyway the idea is to send the request with the `If-Modified-Since` header set with the date you want (self explanatory) and the server will response with a `304 Not Modified` if the file has not changed. Otherwise it returns perhaps a `200 OK` with the contents of the file. I don't know if the above will handle that automatically.

Comment: The above will defintely do it automaticlly aswell.

Comment: No, this looks like you're downloading the file, comparing its modified time with the local time, and if it's out of date, downloading it **again**. As has been pointed out, you need to use If-Modified-Since to get the web server to do the date comparison *before* sending you the file.

Comment: Yeah dude, this kicks off a download of the whole file just to check the modified date (you don't complete the download, but you also don't dispose the object or close the connection, so you're wasting resources in the background). -- Anyway, in addition to what others have said, you can instead keep your current code pattern, and just specify that it use the "HEAD" verb instead of "GET".  -- You can do that by adding a line (before where you declare `gameFileResponse`), that reads `gameFile.Method = "HEAD";`.  (Also, you should dispose your response object when you're done with it!!)

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 You are about 5 years late mate ;) But I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, I'm aware -- I'm just putting it out there for other folks who are late to the party as well. :-)